# Ridge Polynomial Regression: Direct implementation in python

Tags: python, regression

I want to directly implement the ridge polynomial regression in python without using related libraries such as sklearn. The direct calculation is given by:

w = (XTX + lambda * I)^-1*XTy.

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('data.xlsx')
data = wb['data']
xv=[]
yv=[]
for i in range(1,100):
    
    xv = xv +[float(data.cell(row=i,column=1).value)]
    yv = yv +[float(data.cell(row=i,column=2).value)]

n=5 #polynomial degree

ex=1
m=len(xv)

max=xv[0]
for u in range(1,m):
    if xv[u]>max:
        max=xv[u]
        
x=[]
for i in range(0,m):
    xn=[]
    for j in range(0,n+1):
        xn=xn+[xv[i]**j]
    x=x+[xn]

lam = 5
X=np.array(x)
XtX=(X.T).dot(X)
#XtX_inv=np.linalg.inv(XtX)
Xty=(X.T).dot(np.array(yv))
I = np.identity(XtX.shape[0])
LI = np.dot(lam, I) 
XtXLI = np.add(XtX, LI)
XtXLI_inv = XtX_inv=np.linalg.inv(XtXLI)
teta=XtXLI_inv.dot(Xty)

def h(c):
    h=0
    for i in range(0,n+1):
        h=h+teta[i]*c**i
    return h

hv=[]
for i in range(0,m):
    hv=hv+[h(xv[i])]
```

It is expected to achieve better fitting by tuning the lambda parameter. However, the error increases significantly by increasing the lambda. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You may check this implementation made by me which uses the following formula: A^T * A * x = A^T * B

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DATA = np.array([(-5, 12), (-3, 2), (-2, -7), (-1, -4), (2, 3), (3, 1), (5, 4), (7, 9)])

n, m = DATA.shape

def regression(degree: int):
    A = np.empty(shape=(n, degree + 1))

    for i, data in enumerate(DATA):
        # Evaluates the polynomial in order to get coefficients
        A[i] = np.array([data[0]**x for x in range(degree + 1)])

    # @ is a special python operator which performs matrix multiplication
    x = A.T @ A
    y = A.T @ np.array([d[1] for d in DATA])

    # Solves the linear system
    r = np.linalg.solve(x, y)

    # Evaluates in order to plot values
    x = np.linspace(DATA[0][0], DATA[-1][0], num=1000)
    y = np.array([np.sum(np.array([r[i]*(j**i) for i in range(len(r))])) for j in x])
    # Plots the polynomial
    plt.plot(x, y)

    # Plots the data points
    for data in DATA:
        plt.scatter(*data)

    # y has to be recalculated because linspace creates extra values in order to plot the graph
    y = np.array([np.sum(np.array([r[i] * (d[0] ** i) for i in range(len(r))])) for d in DATA])

    error = sum([abs(DATA[i][1]-y[i])**2 for _ in range(n)])**0.5

    # If the error is too small, it is depreciated
    if error > 1e-10:
        plt.title(f"Degree: {degree}, Error: {error}")
    else:
        plt.title(f"Degree: {degree}, Perfect aproximation")

    plt.show()

for i in range(1, n):
    regression(i)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a good python code for polynomial regression problems. However, my question is about regularized polynomial regression, in which the regularization of the model can be tuned using a hyperparameter. I have tried to improve your code by including the hyperparameter. However, I obtained the same results as my code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the **kind of error** you are talking about. Ridge regression is a way to regularized the polynomial regression. The hyperparameter lambda (or alpha) is used to control how much you want to regularize the model. If you increase lambda, you increase the regularisation of your model : your model will perform worse on your training data but better on your testing data (it will generalize better)

Dont forget to scale your data because Ridge regression is sensitive to the scale of the input features.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have tried to scale the input features, but no improvements were achieved.